# Alignment issue in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, gridbaglayout

Please have a look at the following code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestForm extends JFrame
{
    private JLabel heightLabel, weightLabel, waistLabel, neckLabel, hipsLabel,bfPercentageLabel;

    private JTextField heightTxt, weightTxt, waistTxt, neckTxt, hipsTxt;

    private JPanel centerPanel;
    private JPanel southPanel;
    private JLabel endTargetWeightLabel;
    private JLabel endTargetWeightResultLabel;
    private JLabel fatMustLoseLabel;
    private JLabel fatMustLoseResultLabel;


      public TestForm()
      {
        //Declaring instance variables  
        heightLabel = new JLabel("Height: ");
        weightLabel = new JLabel("Weight: ");
        waistLabel = new JLabel("Waist: ");
        neckLabel = new JLabel("Neck: ");
        hipsLabel = new JLabel("Hips: ");        
        bfPercentageLabel = new JLabel("The Orginal Test Score Is: ");

        heightTxt = new JTextField(7);
        weightTxt = new JTextField(7);
        waistTxt = new JTextField(7);
        neckTxt = new JTextField(7);
        hipsTxt = new JTextField(7);

        endTargetWeightLabel = new JLabel("Your End Target Performance is: ");
        fatMustLoseLabel = new JLabel("Sammple Performance You Must Lose: ");


        endTargetWeightResultLabel = new JLabel("d");
        fatMustLoseResultLabel = new JLabel("e");

        this.add(createNorthPanel(),"North");
        this.add(createCenterPanel(),"Center");
        this.add(createSouthPanel(),"South");
        this.add(new JPanel(),"West");
        this.add(new JPanel(),"East");
        this.setTitle("The Test Form");
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    }

    private JPanel createNorthPanel()
    {
        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();

        northPanel = new JPanel();
        northPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel();
        logoLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/TESTING-LOGO.gif")));

        northPanel.add(logoLabel);

        return northPanel;
    }


    private JPanel createCenterPanel()
    {
        centerPanel = new JPanel();

        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        centerPanel.setLayout(gbl);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,0,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(heightLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,0,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(heightTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,10,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(weightLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,-10,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(weightTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,0,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(waistLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,0,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(waistTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,10,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(neckLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,-10,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(neckTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,7,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(hipsLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 6;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,5,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(hipsTxt,gbc);



        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(50,0,0,0);
        gbc.gridwidth = 6;
        centerPanel.add(bfPercentageLabel,gbc);


        centerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("The Testing Form"));

        centerPanel.setPreferredSize(centerPanel.getPreferredSize());
        centerPanel.validate();

        return centerPanel;

    }


     private JPanel createSouthPanel()
    {
        southPanel = new JPanel();

        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        southPanel.setLayout(gbl);


        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
        southPanel.add(endTargetWeightLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10,5,0,0);
        southPanel.add(endTargetWeightResultLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
        southPanel.add(fatMustLoseLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10,5,0,0);
        southPanel.add(fatMustLoseResultLabel,gbc);

        southPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(centerPanel.getWidth(),100));
        southPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("See Your End Target Weight"));

        return southPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            new TestForm();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The above is the maximum shortened code possible. Removing further more elements will not display the original error.

OK. Now the problem is about alignment. Once you run the code, you will see the following.

[image]

As you can see in there, there elements in the `southPanel` are not aligned well with `centerPanel`. Which means, I expect that `southPanel` JLabels to come into the same line where the `centerPanel` JLabels start. But it ended up in this way. I want the JLabels in `southPanel` to be appeared in the same line where the JLabels of `centerPanel` begins. What I am telling is clearly displayed in the following image. How can I do it? Please help!

[image]

PS: I am attaching the "Test Image" as well, so you can test it if you want.
[image]

Comment: Are you using any IDE like `eclipse` **OR** `Netbeans`. There you can open your form view and make arrangments for alignments by drag and dropping.

Comment: @smit: No. Drag and Drop in Java is not accepted in Java Community. And, Form view is available only if you coded this in a project where it is available

Comment: `drag and drop` is just expression what I mean is you can arrange your fields if you open your file with Windowbuilder Editor

Comment: @smit: I know. You are telling that I can drag and drop buttons, text fields etc. It is a very bad practice. In .NET it is accepted because it seems like they follow MVC by default. But in Java, it is not. I have taken comments about drag and drop from various people including international AI Researchers (My Lecturer) and Critical System Developers (another lecturer), and people I personally know who are having positions at Oracle Forums. According to them, Drag and Drop culture is wasting the whole Java. I agree, because I have seen what people have done with Drag and Drop

Comment: I think you are not getting what I am talking about. I said once you create your form, you can see in Windowbuilder how it looks like, there you can change your alignment. I an not talking about creating form with drag and drop. Any way can you show me those links for lectures you are talking about.

Comment: However, I use Netbeans as you guessed. It cannot use GUIBuilder for code it didn't made by it self http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203625/netbeans-gui-builder-on-existing-code

Comment: So, what you're trying to do is effect the layout decisions across multiple, unrelated containers.  This is not how (the default) layout managers work.  The best you might be able to do, is align both containers to the left (`WEST`) and use `insets` to align the equally from the edge...BUT from your screen shot, the two panels are offset differently, which is just going to make the whole thing more difficult.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Thanks for the reply. But, can you please give me a code example? I can't understand what all of you are saying

Comment: Lot has suggested me to use once GridBagLayout, then how can I add that TitledBorder ? It should surround multiple elements so adding a JPanel and giving a border to it is the solution I know. When I use a different JLabel, I have to use GridBagLayout, because I need to keep the spacings and alignments as you can right now (except the issue).

Comment: About aligning it to the west, I need to have a gap between the JPanels and west and east

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each panel is being centered horizontally, they will not align unless they have the same width.  It would be easier to put them in a common panel and share a `GridBagLayout`.

You could change the top level layout to left-align your components (e.g. in another `GridBagLayout` with WEST/LEFT anchors).

Side note: Those negative insets are going to get you into trouble.
Side note2: instead of setting gridx and gridy manually, look into `REMAINDER`
Side note 3: most of your gbc are indentical.  reuse them.

```
this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
this.add(createLeftPanel(), gbc);
...
```

Comment: Hi, Your answer might be the solution. But since it is less informative, I am not getting what you are exactly saying. Do you mind extending the code snippet or editing my code?

Comment: OK, as you have suggested, lets say I am going to add all of those into one GridBagLayout. But, I got 2 JPanels, I need that "titles" in every JPanel. So how can I do it?

Comment: I guess this is the answer, I made some changes but I think I made some mistakes as well, so the issue is there. But, some other issues I had are gone