# GridBagLayout: Aligning JPanels in one vertical line

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, gridbaglayout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alignment issue in GridBagLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202442/alignment-issue-in-gridbaglayout)

Please have a look at the following code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestForm extends JFrame
{
    private JLabel firstLabel, secondLabel, thirdLabel, fourthLabel, fifthLabel;

    private JTextField firstTxt, secondTxt, thirdTxt, fourthTxt, fifthTxt;

    private JPanel centerPanel;
    private JPanel southPanel;
    private JLabel comboLabel;
    private JComboBox percentageCombo;
    private JLabel endTargetLabel;
    private JLabel mustLoseLabel;

    private GridBagLayout mainLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    private GridBagConstraints mainCons = new GridBagConstraints();

      public TestForm()
      {
        //Declaring instance variables  
        firstLabel = new JLabel("First: ");
        secondLabel = new JLabel("Second: ");
        thirdLabel = new JLabel("Third: ");
        fourthLabel = new JLabel("Fourth: ");
        fifthLabel = new JLabel("Fifth: ");        
        comboLabel = new JLabel("Select System Performance: ");

        firstTxt = new JTextField(7);
        secondTxt = new JTextField(7);
        thirdTxt = new JTextField(7);
        fourthTxt = new JTextField(7);
        fifthTxt = new JTextField(7);

        endTargetLabel = new JLabel("Your End Target Performance is: ");
        mustLoseLabel = new JLabel("Sammple Performance You Must Lose: ");  

        percentageCombo = new JComboBox();
        percentageCombo.addItem("No Value is Set");


       this.setLayout(mainLayout);
        mainCons.gridy = 1;
        mainCons.gridx = 1;
        mainCons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        this.add(createNorthPanel(),mainCons);

        mainCons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        mainCons.gridy = 2;
        mainCons.gridx = 1;
        mainCons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        mainCons.insets = new Insets(15,0,0,0);
        this.add(createCenterPanel(),mainCons);

        mainCons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        mainCons.gridy = 3;
        mainCons.gridx = 1;
        this.add(createSouthPanel(),mainCons);

        this.setTitle("The Test Form");
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    }

    private JPanel createNorthPanel()
    {
        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();

        northPanel = new JPanel();
        northPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel();
        logoLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/TESTING-LOGO.gif")));

        northPanel.add(logoLabel);

        return northPanel;
    }


    private JPanel createCenterPanel()
    {
        centerPanel = new JPanel();

        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        centerPanel.setLayout(gbl);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,0,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(firstLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,0,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(firstTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,10,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(secondLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,-10,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(secondTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,0,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(thirdLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,0,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(thirdTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,10,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(fourthLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,-10,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(fourthTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,7,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(fifthLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 6;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,5,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(fifthTxt,gbc);

        centerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("The Testing Form"));
        centerPanel.validate();

        return centerPanel;

    }


     private JPanel createSouthPanel()
    {
        southPanel = new JPanel();

        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        southPanel.setLayout(gbl);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,0,0,0);
        southPanel.add(comboLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,5,0,0);
        southPanel.add(percentageCombo,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
        southPanel.add(endTargetLabel,gbc);


        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
        southPanel.add(mustLoseLabel,gbc);

        southPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("See Your End Target "));

        return southPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            new TestForm();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I get when I use this code

[image]

But, I need the following

1. Both southPanel and centerPanel should appear in a one vertical line. In here, the southPanel is not in the same line as centerPanel, it is bit more aligned to the right
2. Both Panels should move left a bit (showed in image)
3. Both Panels should have the same size
4. The size of the panels are too small. They should be bit large than now, while not changing the spaces and alignments to its components.

[image]

If you know the answer for at least one question, please help. I am attaching the logo as well.

[image]

Note: Removing more elements from the code will not generate the original issue. That is why this code is bit big.

Comment: most of answeres are presents or two or more forums, again 1) use anchor and don't aling to the CENTER 2) create an matrix for 1st row, by using JLabel (20-50 depends of precision), then you can to fill any row & column in the rest of container, 3) use invisible JComponents (empty JLabel) that creating desired gap, 4) have to accepting that GBC works from coordimates from 1st row, everything else are miracles or dirty hacks

Comment: Please edit your question to say how this question differs from your previous one, [Alignment issue in GridBagLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202442/alignment-issue-in-gridbaglayout)?

Comment: @trashgod: Hi, I can see you all have closed this question claiming it is an duplicate. This is not a duplicate. In that previous question, I am advices to use GridBagLayout as the top layout. This question contains code with that. That answer manages to eliminate some of other issues I had, and make this look like this, which is better than the previous. There is only a slight issue in this code. Please reopen this.

Comment: @mKorbel: Hi, I can see you all have closed this question claiming it is an duplicate. This is not a duplicate. In that previous question, I am advices to use GridBagLayout as the top layout. This question contains code with that. That answer manages to eliminate some of other issues I had, and make this look like this, which is better than the previous. There is only a slight issue in this code. Please reopen this.

Comment: Yeah of course. Now I need some other stuff to clarify. You know, still the width issue is there :( . Thanks for voting for the reopen.

Comment: @Sepala: Please cite any previous related questions and indicate how they differ when posting in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign more "weight" to each of the panels, which will force them to align within the given space.

[image]

```
this.setLayout(mainLayout);
mainCons.gridy = 1;
mainCons.gridx = 1;
mainCons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
mainCons.weightx = 1;
this.add(createNorthPanel(), mainCons);

mainCons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
mainCons.weightx = 1;
mainCons.gridy = 2;
mainCons.gridx = 1;
mainCons.insets = new Insets(15, 0, 0, 0);
this.add(createCenterPanel(), mainCons);

mainCons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
mainCons.weightx = 1;
mainCons.gridy = 3;
mainCons.gridx = 1;
this.add(createSouthPanel(), mainCons);
```

As a side node, you can actually use the same instance of the `GridBagConstraints` and change only those values you need, which make you code a little easier to read (not to mention reduce the amount you need to type ;))

You might like to take a look at [How to use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Comment: And as an additional side note, it is a lot simpler to use `gridx` and `gridy` with the value `GridBagConstraint.RELATIVE` and only change the value of `gridwidth` to `GridBagConstraint.REMAINDER` when you want to indicate that the component is the last of its "row". This makes the "use of the same instance" of a GBC a lot easier, the code is a lot cleaner and more importantly it is a lot easier to maintain when you need to insert a component in the middle. Cheers ;-)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Valid point, I just updated the OP's code (bad me) ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :) . I really appreciate it. Do you know the answers for other questions anyway? :)

Answer (score 4):

Simplest solution would be to choose `BorderLayout` for your JFrame and add your 3 panels, north, center and south, with the constraints `BorderLayout.NORTH, BorderLayout.CENTER` and `BorderLayout.SOUTH`.

Otherwise, you need to modify your `mainCons`:

```
mainCons.weightx = 1.0;
mainCons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
```

`anchor` and `fill` always require that `weightx` and/or `weighty` are set to something bigger than 0.

If you want both panels to have the same "width", you can also set

```
mainCons.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer which one is the fourth?

Comment: Ah, my bad, I thought there was a component between the testing and target panes :P

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: Thanks a lot for the reply. +1 from me. However, I tried your suggestion to use " mainCons.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; ". But it made the width of the JPanels to match the width of the program. That is not I am expecting. The width should be less than the program's width, while the width of both panels are same. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Sepala  Use `insets` on the right to reduce the total width or use an empty border (you can combine multiple borders into one with `BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder()`. You may have to rework a bit how you are laying out your inner components too.

Comment: wow. That is a method I never knew. Thank you!